How to override transitive dependency versions in Maven for SonarQube integration?
I'm working on a Java project that uses the sonar-maven-plugin. This plugin has a transitive dependency on sonar-scanner-api, which causing security vulnerabilities due to its use of Okio (version 1.17.2) and OkHttp (version 3.14.2).
The issue I'm facing is that, despite trying to exclude the old OkHttp and Okio versions and explicitly adding the updated versions in my pom.xml, the old versions still seem to be used during the build and are reported by SonarQube.
Here's what I’ve tried so far:
Adding the updated dependencies directly to the dependencyManagement section:
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>4.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
        <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>

Moving the dependency from dependencyManagement to dependencies:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.4121</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
                <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
                <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>4.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
        <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Despite these steps, OkHttp 3.14.2 and Okio 1.17.2 continue to appear in the dependency tree, and SonarQube still reports the vulnerabilities related to these versions.
Questions:

Why might Maven still be resolving the old versions of OkHttp and Okio despite the exclusions and explicit dependency declarations?
Is there a specific point during the Maven build lifecycle where the plugin dependencies might override the exclusions or added dependencies?
Are there any additional steps or strategies I should try to ensure that the updated versions are used instead of the transitive dependencies?

Additional Info:

Maven version: 3.9.6
Java version: 17.0.7
SonarQube: 4.0.0.4121
OS: Windows 11

project structure as follows:
parent-pom
├── submodule1
└── submodule2


You can add them as <dependencies> of the sonar-maven-plugin, but beware: This might solve the security vulnerability issue, but the plugin might no longer be working properly.
A common approach is to allow certain "dangerous" artifacts during the build, but not as part of the created app. For most vulnerabilities there is no large risk if they are just called as part of a build.
